Bypassing government imposed internet bans
Problem
Since last year, our government has imposed recurring internet restrictions, instructing ISPs to block all IP-based traffic during certain periods. This leaves residents without internet access while still allowing phone calls and SMS to work. I'm trying to understand the nature of this block and how to work around it responsibly for educational purposes.
Observations

DNS Behavior:
When I run a ping command (e.g., ping www.google.com), it successfully resolves the domain to an IP address, but no ICMP echo reply is received.
Does this mean that DNS queries (port 53) are not blocked?

Phone Calls and SMS:
These services remain unaffected during the restrictions, which suggests that traffic for certain protocols or services is exempt from the block.

A VPN app called Apna Tunnel still works despite the restrictions.
How might this app bypass the internet block? Could it be using unconventional ports, tunneling over DNS, or leveraging cellular infrastructure in a unique way?


What I Have Tried

Alternative Broadband Connection:
I accessed a broadband connection from another state where the restrictions were not in effect. While this worked temporarily, it was unreliable and costly.

Custom VPN Setup:
I deployed an OpenVPN server on AWS EC2, configuring it to listen on port 53 (commonly used by DNS traffic). My reasoning was that since DNS queries appear to be functional, running a VPN on this port might bypass the restriction.
Unfortunately, this did not work. I suspect my lack of networking knowledge could be a factor.


Questions

Based on the symptoms, how might this block be implemented? Is it likely port-based, protocol-based, or something more sophisticated like deep packet inspection?

How can I confirm whether DNS traffic (port 53) is genuinely unblocked or if it’s only resolving locally?

What methods might Apna Tunnel be using to bypass these restrictions? Could it involve tunneling traffic over DNS (DoH/DoT) or exploiting exemptions in the cellular network infrastructure?

Are there reliable ways to run a VPN or proxy server under such circumstances? If port 53 doesn’t work, what other protocols or techniques could I explore?


Notes
I understand the need for compliance with local laws and do not intend to misuse this information. This is for educational purposes and to understand how such restrictions function.

Unfortunately, your question is off-topic here.

Where should I ask questions like this?

I do not think there is an SE site for this question.
